# How to set admin user/pwd when launching Nexus docker image

Tags: nexus

When launchin Nexus 2 docker image ( https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus/ ) how to configure it to change the default admin user password to something else than admin/admin123 ?

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Zeitounator, 
thank for you answer but in fact I did manage to change the admin password.
In the docker image you need to update the /sonatype-work/conf/security.xml file.
there is an admin section in which you need to change the password element

```
<user>
  <id>admin</id>
  <firstName>Administrator</firstName>
  <lastName>User</lastName>
  <password>change_password_here</password>
  <status>active</status>
  <email>changeme@yourcompany.com</email>
</user>
```

I am using kubernetes to launch Nexus, and by mounting the proper files I was able to change the password.

In order to generate a password I used the shiro tool hasher cli : https://shiro.apache.org/command-line-hasher.html

Answer (score 2):

To change for the first time the admin password follow the following steps (docker
version only) :

Go to the Nexus container instance for example 91aefe723146

```
  make a docker exec -it 91aefe723146 /bin/bash
```

Go to /nexus-data

```
  get the password content of the file admin.password
```

log again to the admin console and put the password and reinit your password.
Done !

Comment: This is for nexus 3. The question was specifically for nexus 2.