# Nexus return 401 Unauthorized, after build image from Dockerfile

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile, nexus

I'm new in docker, try to google this issue, bit found nothing.

I have to create nexus image from sonatype/nexus3 and change password in admin.password file after creating image.

It's my **Dockerfile**:

```
FROM sonatype/nexus3

WORKDIR /nexus-data
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "echo root >> admin.password"]
```

and when i check the file admin.password (**docker exec <container> cat admin.password**) i have this result:
**root**

And Authorization works if i run continer from sonatype/nexus3 image from docker hub (with default UUID password).

What should i do?

I am thinking that maybe i rewrite admin profile or delete it somehow?

Answer (score 0):

The way it works is that the sonatype/nexus3 image contains an already installed version and the random password has been written to admin.password. But it's just a log, not the password used to confgure nexus.

What you want to do has already been answered here [How to set admin user/pwd when launching Nexus docker image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56392814/how-to-set-admin-user-pwd-when-launching-nexus-docker-image)

Comment: Thanks for link. I've seen it, but i do not have this file in container(( i tried to create it, but it still doesn't work. That is why i created this topic.

Comment: And if i change admin.password after run container in bash with echo it will work.

Comment: As mentioned in the doc, this file is written into the persistent volume so you must add one
`Default user is admin and the uniquely generated password can be found in the admin.password file inside the volume. See Persistent Data for information about the volume.` Look at the persistent data section https://hub.docker.com/r/sonatype/nexus3/#user-content-persistent-data

Comment: The linked answer gives a solution when running `sonatype:nexus:latest` which is the image for nexus version 2. Automating password change after starting a service out of `sonatype:nexus3:latest` is possible using the API and some basic scripting.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a detailed walkthrough to change the admin password from the CLI after starting a fresh nexus3 docker container. You can easily script that once you understand how it works.

*Important note to clear a possible misunderstanding: you don't build a nexus3 image containing predefined data like your admin password. You start a fresh image which will initialize fresh data when using an empty `nexus-data` volume, including a random admin password and you use that password to change it to your own value.*

1. Start a docker container from the official image. Note: this is a minimal and trashable (i.e. `--rm`) start just for the example. Read the documentation to secure your data.

   ```
   docker run -d --rm --name testnexus -p 8081:8081 sonatype/nexus3:latest
   ```
2. Wait a bit for nexus to start (you can check the logs with `docker logs testnexus`) then read the generated password into a variable:

   ```
   CURRENT_PASSWORD=$(docker exec testnexus cat /nexus-data/admin.password)
   ```
3. Set the expected admin password into an other variable

   ```
   NEW_PASSWORD=v3rys3cur3
   ```
4. Use the Nexus API to change the admin password:

   ```
   curl -X PUT \
   -u "admin:${CURRENT_PASSWORD}" \
   -d "${NEW_PASSWORD}" \
   -H 'accept: application/json' \
   -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
   http://localhost:8081/service/rest/v1/security/users/admin/change-password
   ```
5. Access Nexus GUI with your browser at `http://localhost:8081`, login with your newly changed password, enjoy.